# How to change page margins only for pages including graphics with the [p] option

Tags: floats, margins

I would like to reduce the page margins in my document only for those pages which include a figure embedded using the [p] option, in order to have some more space for my figures, as in:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{filename}
\end{figure}
```

A minimum working example is not feasible as this would require an image to be embedded, but I hope the question will be clear enough nonetheless.

Comment: to make an MWE with images, you could use the filename `example-image-a`, among a few others.

Comment: What to do with headers and footers in these figure pages?

Comment: @RunarTrollet Worth mentioning that the example-images so often used are associated with the `mwe` package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes don't need the `mwe` package for that. `graphicx` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to place an oversized image inside of a box that is the normal `\textwidth` in size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{example-image-A}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need captioning, one would need to know if the caption is also to be oversized or not.  Below, I show oversized captioning.  I place an oversized `minipage` into the normal width `\makebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\makebox[\textwidth]{\begin{minipage}{1.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A}

\caption{\protect\lipsum[2]}
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]